# Can I use WMI to manage WSD devices (specifically printers)?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi, wsd

I am using WMI with C# to enumerate and modify the printers on my computer.

I'm running Windows 7, and everything is working fine when I try to modify printers that are installed "classically". By "classically", I mean that the printer is just using a basic TCP/IP Port. I can rename it, set it as the default printer, etc. using the documented WMI functions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363(v=vs.85).aspx.

However, by default Windows is installing my printer as a WSD (Web Services on Devices) printer. When this happens, the printer uses a WSD Port, which I can't seem to touch using WMI.

In the screenshot below, you can see that my printer is using a "WSD Port". Below that port is the standard TCP/IP Port that my printer uses when installed without WSD.

[image: Screenshot]

The software that came with my printer installs the printer using a standard TCP/IP port. However, when I manually install my printer, Windows chooses the WSD port.

WMI seems to have no definition for WSD enabled devices. Does anyone know if this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in your WMI, all printers shown in your Devices and Printers are listed on WMI.  To give you an example I have a similar situation where I have a printer using the WSD portname and we can manage it from code.

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use the WMI interface to modify the printers, like you can with standard printers?

Comment: What do you mean by WMI Interface?  BTW I am using System.Management.ManagementClass

Comment: For example, the `Win32_Printer class` has a few methods you can invoke: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394363(v=vs.85).aspx - These methods were not working with WSD printers.

Comment: I never had issues with it, how did you implemented it in your codes?  Here is a blog post of mine that explains managing printers in C# might be worth to look at http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/managing-printers-programatically-using-c-and-wmi/

Comment: What a coincidence, I have been using that code. Let me try again; I probably just did something stupid. Thanks!