# PowerShell Printer port property hostaddress not always populated

Tags: powershell, wmi, printers

We're trying to create a list of all the printers on a print server with their respective `HostAddress` for the shared port they use. To do this we created the following function:

```
Function Get-PrintersInstalledHC {
    Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [Object[]]$Servers
    )
    Process {
        foreach ($S in $Servers) {
            Try {
                if ($Printers = Get-Printer -ComputerName $S.Name -Full -EA Stop) {
                    $CimParams = @{
                        ClassName    = 'Win32_PrinterConfiguration'
                        ComputerName = $S.Name
                        Property     = '*'
                        ErrorAction  = 'Stop'
                    }                
                    $Details = Get-CimInstance @CimParams

                    $Ports = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort -ComputerName $S.Name -Property *

                    Foreach ($P in $Printers) {
                        Foreach($D in $Details) {
                            if ($P.Name -eq $D.Name) {
                                $Prop = @{
                                    PortHostAddress = $Ports | Where {$_.Name -eq $P.PortName} | 
                                                        Select -ExpandProperty HostAddress
                                    DriverVersion   = $D.DriverVersion
                                    Collate         = $D.Collate
                                    Color           = $D.Color
                                    Copies          = $D.Copies
                                    Duplex          = $D.Duplex
                                    PaperSize       = $D.PaperSize
                                    Orientation     = $D.Orientation
                                    PrintQuality    = $D.PrintQuality
                                    MediaType       = $D.MediaType
                                    DitherType      = $D.DitherType
                                    RetrievalDate   = (Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
                                }
                                $P | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $Prop -TypeName NoteProperty
                                Break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName   = $S.Name
                        ComputerStatus = 'Ok'
                        RetrievalDate  = (Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
                        Printers       = $Printers
                    }
                }
            }
            Catch {
                if (Test-Connection $S.Name -Count 2 -EA Ignore) {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName   = $S.Name
                        ComputerStatus = "ERROR: $($Error[0].Exception.Message)" 
                        RetrievalDate  = (Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
                        Printers       = $null
                    }
                }
                else {
                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName   = $S.Name
                        ComputerStatus = 'Offline'
                        RetrievalDate  = (Get-Date -Format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
                        Printers       = $null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function works fine in a mixed environment and gives us the full list of all the printers installed on a server with their properties. However, the property `HostAddress` (renamed to `PortHostAddress` in the function above) is not always populated.

This is also illustrated with the following code, as not all printers are in the output:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Printer -ComputerName $PrintServer | ForEach-Object { 
    $Printer = $_.Name
    $Port = $_.PortName
    Get-WmiObject Win32_TCPIpPrinterPort -ComputerName $PrintServer | where {$_.Name -eq $Port} | 
        select @{Name="PrinterName";Expression={$Printer}}, HostAddress 
}
```

For 90% of all printers the `HostAddress` can be found with this code. But sometimes it can't be found and the field stays empty because there is no match between the `Name` and the `PortName`.

Is there a better way of retrieving this property that works a 100% of the time?

Comment: Hmm. Check what printers do not have a `HostAddress` populated, probably these are software-based printers like "Print to PDF" or similar.

Comment: Solid advise Vesper, but I checked that already. These printers are normal printers, like say HP and Konica Minolta. On a list of over 500 printers we only have 12 that don't have the `PortHostAddress` populated. Other printers of the same brands on the same server don't have this problem. Very strange..

Comment: Do they print anywhere? Do they have ports assigned? What are the types of those ports, if not IP_xxxx? (DOT_xxx, maybe, these use a WINS-type name resolution to find the printer)

Comment: Great tip this one! Didn't think there would be different types of ports with regards to IP. The ones that don't have a `HostAddress` are the ones that don't have a `Standard TCP/IP Port` assigned but rather one of these types of port: `HP Standard TCP/IP Port`, `WSD Port`, `Local port`, `Advanced TCP/IP Port monitor`. So we found the culprit here :) How is it possible to retrieve these values?

Comment: Thank you Vesper. I think the best thing to do is to convert these to the `Microsoft Standard TCP/IP Port` as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/kb/2411921). For now, I've updated the code as following: `$PortHostAddress = $Ports | Where {$_.Name -eq $P.PortName} | Select -ExpandProperty HostAddress $Prop = @{PortHostAddress = if($PortHostAddress){$PortHostAddress}else{"Not Standard TCP/IP Port"}`

Comment: If a port is of type "Local port" use the computer's IP address as host address (as these ports are purely software-based). For WSD ports, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089262/can-i-use-wmi-to-manage-wsd-devices-specifically-printers and for advanced ports, maybe convert em into standard ports as well (create new standard ports with same IP address+port combination, then reassign the printer to print through standard TCP/IP port and check if it works), if it won't work, try querying that type of ports for known attributes manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82293/discussion-between-darklite1-and-vesper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the additional data states the problem ports are using drivers different from Microsoft's TCP/IP printer port driver, parsing these ports' addresses would require interacting with the drivers, this is dependant on the driver in question. So skip it, or convert a remote port to Microsoft's "Standard TCP/IP port" if possible. HP printers are easily converted, WSD printers can be converted by creating a TCP/IP port with the IP address of a WSD printer and assigning a static IP address on that printer, and about the same procedure could work with "Advanced TCP/IP port"s. The ports that are labeled "Local" ports are software-based, and you can use the host's IP address in place of missed `PortHostAddress`.